# Can I set the Sender ID For CDMA SMS

Tags: sms, sender, cdma

Is it possible to set the Sender ID alphanumerically to a CDMA device, 'cos I tried, but anytime I use anything other than numerics, the message does not arrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Google search for "alphanumeric sender CDMA" should be all you need to answer your question: CDMA networks don't support alphanumeric sender IDs.